# MYSQL grouping months together with limit

Tags: mysql

Hi I am using the following query

```
SELECT
    FROM_UNIXTIME(
        results.date_searched,
        '%M %Y'
    ) AS mon,
    results.region AS region,
    results.country AS country,
    results.resort AS resort,
    Count(results.region) AS num
FROM
    home_monthly_cached_data
RIGHT JOIN results ON home_monthly_cached_data.`month` = FROM_UNIXTIME(
    results.date_searched,
    '%M/%Y'
 )
WHERE
    results.region != 'Not Available'
AND results.region != ''
AND results.country != ''
AND results.country != 'Turkey'
GROUP BY
    results.region
ORDER BY
mon,    
COUNT(*) DESC
```

To generate the following

[image]
I wanted the results display ONLY 5 results for each month

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy (SQL) way. You can do it with multiple queries, each with a limit, or you can do the whole query, fetch all IDs and months, sort the array, and go back to fetch the actual rows by ID - the good solution depends on a couple of things.

A very simple case is when you only have 2-3 months to look ahead, and in this case, nothing actually beats 2-3 separate queries.  Also, if you only have a few (1-2000) rows, separate queries will do even for more months - because MySQL probably holds the whole table cached even after the first query.

If you have about 10.000 rows, PHP fetching-sorting will work the best. If your rows are slow to get (because of the join, for example), it's a benefit that you'll only need to fetch them once and do the rest from PHP (or whatever you're querying from).

Over 500.000, arrays start to spill out of memory so you might want a tmp table or a tmp file to hold your rows.  It's still fast if you do it right.

Now if you have over a million rows, and you still want to pick only 5 from each month, a lot of other factors come in so I'll describe this case only if necessary.

(THEN AGAIN, maybe there's something about MySQL that I don't know and solves your problem...)

Comment: Thank you so much, I will have to use Php for now, but soon will be caching it into a different table as this data will not change.

Comment: In that case all you need is a new structure. If it REALLY doesn't change at all, you can also store months serialized into a file - it's much faster than MySQL.  But it's your call now - my answer aimed at the one-bit information you asked - it's a zero :)